# Using length and width ratio for Responsive CSS

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

### Question

Can I use length and width ratio to change CSS file? If length is greater than width then device must be cellphone or tablet and ratio must be grater than one. And if ratio is less than one that means device must be desktop or phone is switched to landscape mode!?
And if it is so, then I can easily use JavaScript to change CSS file for different platforms! I'm I right or not?

Answer (score 0):

When building websites with the [mobile-first approach](https://medium.com/@Vincentxia77/what-is-mobile-first-design-why-its-important-how-to-make-it-7d3cf2e29d00), you can change elements according to the screen width of the device. To overwrite properties for all screens bigger than e.g. 649px:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) { 
    h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
        margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You easily use CSS media queries for that
Checkout:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp 
So you will be able to set query for landscape, portrait, print, screen and so on. 
Or specify different css style using Javascript at each query 
Checkout :
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_matchmedia.asp